# Buildout not using pinned versions

Tags: python, django, buildout

When I try to run buildout for a existing project, which used to work perfectly
fine, it now installs the incorrect version of Django, even though the version
is pinned.

For some reason, it's installing Django 1.10 even though I've got 1.6 pinned. (I
know that's an old version, but client doesn't want me to upgrade just yet.)

Here is a very trucated version of the the buildout config file.

```
[buildout]
index = https://pypi.python.org/simple
versions = versions
include-site-packages = false
extensions = mr.developer
unzip = true
newest = false

parts = ...
auto-checkout = *

eggs =
    <... Many eggs here ...>
    Django
    <... Many more eggs ...>


[base-versions]
...
Django = 1.6.1
...


[versions]
<= base-versions
```

The only other thing that I can think of that could possibly make an impact
is that I recently reinstalled my system to Kubuntu 18.04 (Was previously Ubuntu 17.10)

Comment: Hmm, looks like the issue is with extending the `[versions]` section. It looks like that feature doesn't work with versions. As soon as I replaced it all it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working is because the `[versions]` part cannot be extended

Answer (score -1):

Pip can install a specific version of library using pip, you can try:

pip install django==1.6.1

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help me. The versions are managed by zc.buildout, not pip.